# Joining tables from different locations in Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud

I have been trying to join two tables from different datasets that are in different locations but in the same project. However, I keep  getting the error:

```
dataset not found in US location.
```

The datasets' locations are US and us-east1

Here is what I am doing:

```
select a.*, b.* from `project.dataset1.table1` a join `project.dataset2.table2`
on a.common_col = b.common_col
```

Please help me out on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot join two tables from different datasets that are in different locations. As an alternative solution, you can copy datasets between regions using `BigQuery Data Transfer Service`. Here is the documentation link [Copying Datasets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets#bq):

```
bq mk --transfer_config \
      --project_id=myproject \
      --data_source=cross_region_copy \
      --target_dataset=dataset_us \
      --display_name='Copy Dataset' \
      --params='{"source_dataset_id":"dataset_eu","source_project_id":"myproject"}'
```

Comment: Is there no other way to set jobs to read from multiple different locations? I'm facing the same issue and seems to be frustrating that data run in US and us-east1 can't be run together. Feels like we have to restructure our complete data locations

Answer (score 2):

Too late to answer but writing here for future reference.

You cannot query data from multiple different locations at the same time. The **alternate solution** is as below:

1. Query the data from Location-1
2. Save its results in form of CSV or any other preferrable format (Saving CSV in Google Drive works up to 1GB of output)
3. Create a table in dataset that's lying under Location-2
4. Import the CSV file you saved into this newly created table
5. Query the data on Location-2 with your Location-2 data and saved table